# Angular 2 Md Slider change event, value remains the same

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a typescript angular 4 frontend project where i want to change the initial value of a md slider element and on change event make a web api call with that changed value. The change event is called when i move the slider in the page but on the change event in my component the value remains what it was initially. How do I get the changed value in my component so that I can make a web api call ?

Comment: Could you post example code of what you've tried? Relevant html and corresponding component typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `$event.value` from view to component. The `$event.value` emits the new value.

Example:

```
<md-slider (change)="someFucn($event.value)"></md-slider>
```

ts:

```
someFucn(newVal){
  alert("Slider val: " + newVal);
  // Add API code here
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/depkkZKuNlMULUC9PmF0?p=preview)